# Use maven to update script

Tags: java, bash, maven, deployment, maven-release-plugin

I have a Java project that's paired with a bash script to make it easier to deploy on Linux. The script is a lot more complicated than this, but the part that matters is a section like this:

```
directory="/default/install/directory"
jarName = "myApp-0.0.1.jar"
command="/usr/bin/java -DARG=$argValue -jar $directory/$jarName"
```

When I update the version to 0.0.2, I would like maven to automatically change this line in my script, simply to:

```
jarName = "myApp-0.0.2.jar"
```

I'm sure this would involve `maven-release-plugin` in some way - possibly with `sed -i`, but my development machine is Windows so such tools are not so readily available (though I do use cygwin) - but I'm not really sure how. Thanks!

Comment: Why not putting the script inside the resources, changing 'jarName = "myApp-${project.version}.jar"', so that Maven filters automatically the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is typically done by placing these kind of scripts as Maven resources.
Using Maven properties ('jarName = "myApp-${project.version}.jar"') instead of hardcoded values, and activating filtering on these resources will make this straightforward.

If these scripts should be packaged in a different way than just inside the JAR produced, the assembly plugin will be able to do the job.

Comment: It was a resource, I just had filtering set to false because I didn't understand what it was for until I read your comment. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Indeed, I updated the answer to point to filtering more explicitly